# Network working extremely slow on Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: networking, network-manager

I have a weird problem with my OS recently. I am running Ubuntu 21.04 on Dell XPS15 9500 but recently network started to be extremely slow... well, not everything is slow - more like something at the beginning of connection is crazy so for instance pages load for ages but for instance downloads or video buffering runs fine at stable 70-80 Mbit/s.

When I use VPN the problem disappears so I thought it was something with my home network but I checked using second laptop and Windows 10 (pretty much identical hardware) and there the problem did not appear.

I also checked DNS settings and verified that both Ubuntu and Windows receive the same DNS settings pointing to my router - one address on IPv4 and one on IPv6.

What should I check to investigate (and fix) the exact issue?

```
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Comet Lake PCH CNVi WiFi
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlp0s20f3
       version: 00
       serial: 3c:58:c2:6d:30:53
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.11.0-22-generic firmware=59.601f3a66.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-59.u ip=192.168.2.202 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff irq:16 memory:604b11c000-604b11ffff
```

Comment: Try to ping to a v4 address (e.g. `1.1.1.1`) and to a v6 address (e.g. `2a00:1450:4002:806::200e`). Is the time something appropriate (e.g. < 100m)? ***If both are OK***, try to resolve some addresses; you may have a DNS problem.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli Ping on both of the above works fine. But what could I check with DNS considering that Windows gets exact same DNS settings via DHCP and works fine? Also, I tried to provide custom DNS (`8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`) but that did not help...